# How does the compareTo() method, compare strings?

Tags: java, string, interface, comparable, compareto

Such as if I were to compare the Strings "Hello" and "World".

How does it know Hello is greater than World?

The only thing I can come up with is, maybe it uses the ASCII Table as reference?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you looked at the [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)? My bet is that much is to be found there. Edit, yep, I'm correct. It's all spelled out there, and that should be the first place you look for questions like these -- and definitely before asking this type of question here.

Comment: Isn't "Hello" less than "World"?

Comment: It's explained in detail [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: `"Hello"` is *less* than `"World"`, but `"hello"` is greater than `"World"` (upper vs. lower case).

Comment: lol closed as localized but 27k views and actually helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it compares two strings *lexographically*. 
check here in the [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29).

> If two strings are different, then either they have different
>   characters at some index that is a valid index for both strings, or
>   their lengths are different, or both. If they have different
>   characters at one or more index positions, let k be the smallest such
>   index; then the string whose character at position k has the smaller
>   value, as determined by using the < operator, lexicographically
>   precedes the other string.

Answer (score 2):

All uppercase are preceding lowercase so:

```
"Be".compareTo("ay");
```

will return a negative value, which means "less-than".

Comment: and what if I have more than 2 strings in list. How does comparison takes place? I mean index wise (0,1) (1,2)

Comment: The code you've included returns "-31". `compareTo` returns the non-zero  ASCII difference of the two strings.

Comment: @GaurangTandon Thanks. Edited post.

Comment: I always thought that *preceding* means that uppercase has a *higher* priority than lowercase which makes `"Be".compareTo("ay")>0` :(

Comment: @Arefly Yeah that's confusing, but if you look at it in terms of "less-than", "equals-to" and "greater-than" things are easier to remember. This is how it is described in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-).